# How to convert secured HTML (ASP.NET MVC 3) page to PDF using wkhtmltopdf?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I would like to convert a HTML + CSS page to a PDF file.
I have tried [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) and I have got a problem because the page I want to access requires to be authenticated on the Website.

The page I would like to convert to PDF has the following URL : http://[WEBSITE]/PDFReport/33

If I try to access it without being authenticated, I'm redirected to the login page.

So when I use wkhtmltopdf, it converts my login page to PDF...

The anthentication method I use on my ASP.NET MVC application is SimpleMembership:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult PDFReport(string id)
{
}
```

I am executing wkhtmltopdf.exe with System.Diagnostics.Process :

```
FileInfo tempFile = new FileInfo(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "\\bin\\test.pdf");

StringBuilder argument = new StringBuilder();
argument.Append(" --disable-smart-shrinking");
argument.Append(" --no-pdf-compression");
argument.Append(" " + "http://[WEBSITE]/PDFReport/33");
argument.Append(" " + tempFile.FullName);

// to call the exe to convert
using (Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process())
{
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    p.StartInfo.FileName = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "\\bin\\wkhtmltopdf.exe";
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = argument.ToString();
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

    p.Start();
    p.WaitForExit();
}
```

Do you know how to generate the PDF without disabling security on this page?

Answer (score 1):

I had a good deal of trouble with this recently. In a nutshell, WKHTMLTOPDF is a version of Webkit (QT, I believe they call it), so when you request a password protected page, *that* browser needs to log in and store/reference a cookie the same as you would normally.

The raw call would look something like this:

`/path/wkhtmltopdf --cookie-jar my.jar --username myusername --password mypassword URL

Where:

- `my.jar` is a jar file that gets created and holds your cookie values
- `username` is the `name` of the username form field and `myusername` is the post value
- `password` is the `name` of the password form field and `mypassword` is the post value
- `URL` is the URL of the log in page

Be sure to include any other post fields required to successfully log in - you'll probably want to monitor your HTTP headers, not just look at the form. Call WKHTMLTOPDF again on the page you're looking to capture with your normal parameters, including the --cookie-jar my.jar to maintain the session. That should do it!

However, I still had problems on my end, but it was a fairly robust login (multiple cookies, secure, many parameters, etc). I was working with PHP and had better luck using CURL - I'm not sure how that carries over to ASP.NET (maybe this? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303436) but here's my logic if it helps:

- Log in via CURL
- Grab HTML page and store in local temporary file
- Replace all relative references to images and files to absolute references (or insert a `base` tag)
- Run plain 'ol WKHTMLTOPDF on the temporary file
- Delete temporary file

All in all it was a hell of a lot easier to do it this way, and it feels better to me knowing I'm leaning on tried and true code rather than parameters in version 0.10 of WKHTMLTOPDF.